# window.plugins.calendar.modifyEventWithOptions not working in Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin will not support modify events in android is there any other way to do so, or any other plugin that can i use to update android native calendar events from my app

I am using Codrova ionic

Please help me regarding this

Thank u

Comment: What is the all day native calendar events insert format for android 6.0

Comment: even in iOS its not updating...

Comment: for me its working